# Find h2 within first li only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want jquery to target a h2 within first li of a carousel to which I will then add some css to.

As a basic example I have this so far

```
$('li').first().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Which is only targeting the li. How do I then go onto target the h2 to apply the css to? Would it be using the .find property?

I know I can do this within CSS but would like to do it in the jquery as it will have other features added to it in the jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Would it be using the .find property?"*

Well, yes, the [`find()` *method*](http://api.jquery.com/find) (not property) is one way to do it:

```
// all h2 elements within the first li:
$('li').first().find('h2').css('background-color', 'red');
// or just the first h2 within the first li:
$('li').first().find('h2').first().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can try if `h2` is one level down in DOM to `li`:

```
// all h2 elements within the first li:
$('li').first().children('h2').css('background-color', 'red');
```

because find() multilevel which make it slow.

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well. [documented here](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('li:first h2').css('background-color', 'red');
```